# php and JavaScript zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, api

What i'm trying to do is when a user enters a zip code in the input type i get the value of the input type store in **origin_zipcode** than add **origin_zipcode** inside the **$url** variable. From there it should run the xml and i should be able to display the city and state but it doesn't do that it im trying to make it work like

https://ship.onemorepallet.com/shipment/start?hsCtaTracking=296d76b9-a6fc-4140-83f9-de066c986716|9001d544-e760-4dae-ac72-36cc2922be55?utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onemorepallet.com%2F

when you enter in the zip code

```
$("#origin_zipcode").keyup(function(){
var origin_zipcode = $("#origin_zipcode").val();

<?php
$url = "http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/gNPseXsQyP3daTlKfRB3D0v0mPVC3jJj6zMlwec54fie8EZowAsaBXaXN5zQpjav/info.xml/origin_zipcode/degree";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$city = $xml->city;
$state = $xml->state;
?>

$(".labelzip").text(<?php echo $city,$state"; ?>);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a jQuery variable to a PHP script unless you refresh the page using one of a few possible methods.  This is because while jQuery is *client-side*, php is *server-side*.  After PHP has finished loading the page, it can't be used again without a page reload.

You can look at these questions for a possible solutions:

- [How to pass jQuery variables to PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202070/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-php-variable)
- [jquery 'variable' to php 'variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267468/jquery-variable-to-php-variable)
- [how to pass a jquery variable to php and then display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833008/how-to-pass-a-jquery-variable-to-php-and-then-display-it)

Comment: OP can also use AJAX, instead of a page reload, but the basic point in this answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed, but doesn't ajax still reload the page?

Comment: No. It calls another resource, without reloading the active page. It could call the same script that was used to generate the page, but it doesn't have to.